# Aggregate initialization, clang wants me to break my code?

Tags: c++, stdarray

Why does clang suggest me to add additional braces when initializing my 2 dimensional standard array? Which would lead to an error. Or am I just not seeing what he wants me to do?

I know that i can add outer braces that would make it clear that i am intializing the first member of the class, but that does not make the warnings go away. I don't think i can add any other braces though.

Compiled on Godbolt with 
clang9.0.0 `-O0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wno-unused-value`

[Link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::array%3Cstd::array%3Cfloat,+3%3E,+3%3E+%7B%0A++++++++1,2,3,%0A++++++++1,2,3,%0A++++++++1,2,3%0A++++%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++std::array%3Cstd::array%3Cfloat,+3%3E,+3%3E+%7B%7B%0A++++++++1,2,3,%0A++++++++1,2,3,%0A++++++++1,2,3%0A++++%7D%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang900,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wno-unused-value%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+9.0.0+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```cpp
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> {
        1,2,3,
        1,2,3,
        1,2,3
    };

    std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> {{
        1,2,3,
        1,2,3,
        1,2,3
    }};
}
```

I would be ok if the warning would tell me to do the second variant in my example, but it seems that he wants me to wrap the inner array member, which you can't do.

For some information about aggregate initialization: [CppRefference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two versions to create two equal arrays:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> a {{
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3}
    }};

    std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 3> b = {{
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3},
        {1,2,3}
    }};
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are both lists the same?

Comment: @NathanOliver There's a `=` in the second, otherwise exactly the same. :-)

Comment: Ah, okay.  I thought you were saying there were two versions of the list.

Comment: @NathanOliver Aha, nope, added a note. Not sure if I made it clearer. :-/

Comment: Thanks for that, i only tested either the inner 3 members in braces or the additional outer braces. I was sure i tested both together, but as it seems i did not.